# boost asio coroutine scheduling time

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost, boost-asio

Is asio like golang's coroutine (G) still running on top of the worker thread (M), but with the help of the language's scheduler, the coroutine only needs to be switched in user mode, and the worker thread is unaware of the coroutine's existence. So which thread is responsible for the execution of the coroutine, and how is this relationship determined?

Comment: I'm reasonably happy to quote the documentation for you, but I'd like to remind you that learning Asio by asking questions on stackoverflow is not the most effective way. Instead, pick a goal, implement it (by per-using the [doc examples](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html) as well as [library examples](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/tree/develop/example). Then, ask questions here if they aren't already answered!

Answer (score 0):

You decide which threads potentially run async operations (initiating functions or handlers).

The documentation is here: [Concurrency Without Threads](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/async.html)

The requirements and guarantees made by the library are documented here: [Threads](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/threads.html). Notable excerpt:

> The implementation of this library for a particular platform may make use of one or more internal threads to emulate asynchronicity. As far as possible, these threads must be invisible to the library user. In particular, the threads:
>
> - must not call the user's code directly; and
> - must block all signals.
>
> This approach is complemented by the following guarantee:
>
> - Asynchronous completion handlers will only be called from threads that are currently calling io_context::run().
>
> Consequently, it is the library user's responsibility to create and manage all threads to which the notifications will be delivered.
>
> The reasons for this approach include:
>
> - By only calling io_context::run() from a single thread, the user's code can avoid the development complexity associated with synchronisation. For example, a library user can implement scalable servers that are single-threaded (from the user's point of view).
> - A library user may need to perform initialisation in a thread shortly after the thread starts and before any other application code is executed. For example, users of Microsoft's COM must call CoInitializeEx before any other COM operations can be called from that thread.
> - The library interface is decoupled from interfaces for thread creation and management, and permits implementations on platforms where threads are not available.